# Using Euclidean Algorithm to find 2 variables

Tags: algorithm

I have `ab-cd = 1` where a, b, c, d are integers and I am given `a` and `c`. I was told I can use the Euclidean algorithm to find both `b` and `d`, but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Comment: So: a, b, c, d are integers?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the GCD is 1 so the LCM is `a*c`.  This does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just trace it through.

The Euclidean Algorithm starts with a pair of numbers, and replaces it with a new pair of numbers.  Like this:

```
(x, y) -> (y, x - (x//y) * y)
```

You start with `(a, c)` and do this repeatedly until you get a pair where one divides the other.

But we can in parallel look at each number as a linear combination of our original two.  So if `x = i*a + j*c` we can represent this with `(i, j)`.  And ditto `y` can be represented with `(k, l)`.  But now we can represent the operation as follows...

```
((i, j), (k, l)) -> ((k, l), (i - (x//y) * k, j - (x//y) * l))
```

And in this parallel representation we start with `((1, 0), (0, 1))`.  And when we finally get to 1, we now know our answer!

This may seem a little abstract, let's give a real example.  Let's do `a = 15` and `c = 11`.

```
(15, 11) -> (11,  4) | x//y = 1 | (( 1,  0), ( 0,  1)) -> (( 0,  1), ( 1, -1))
(11,  4) -> ( 4,  3) | x//y = 2 | (( 0,  1), ( 1, -1)) -> (( 1, -1), (-2,  3))
( 4,  3) -> ( 3,  1) | x//y = 1 | (( 1, -1), (-2,  3)) -> ((-2,  3), ( 3, -4))
```

And so I claim that `3 * 15 + (-4) * 11 = 1`.  Which, in fact, it does.

You just have to carry out the operation with the numbers, and carry out the parallel operation correctly with the ordered pairs, and the last one is your answer.

Comment: Thank you. This does solve the problem. How did you come up with the parallel operation?

Comment: @c6681215 I just looked for a way to explain that the numbers that show up in the operation are explicit linear combinations of the two numbers that you started with.  And that was a good way to represent it.